# IPv6 privacy extension tab missing from network manager

Tags: network-manager, ipv6

I have two machines. One running Wily Werewolf Ubuntu 15.10 and the other running 14.04.4 LTS, Trusty Tahr.

Whatever you call the network connection app in the upper right-hand corner of the screen (because I've heard it referred to as both NetworkAdmin and network-manager depending on which internet search link you click on) on the 15.10 machine under "edit connections" | "IPV6 settings" there is an option for "IPv6 privacy extensions", whereas on the 14.04 machine no such option exists.

Both machines have exactly the same networking parameters and are setup to benefit from IPV6.